# TSQL How to make where clause match all 'IN' multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I am using 4 dates in my where clause using `IN`. For example

```
...where date in ('2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03','2017-01-04')
```

My query will return a result if even one date matches but I want my where clause to match ALL the dates. I'm sure there has to be an easy solution for this.

Comment: How can a date column, containing a single date, match multiple dates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to match your data for a specific column value. Group by that column and take only those groups having all 4 dates

```
select col
from your_table
where date in ('2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03','2017-01-04')
group by col
having count(distinct date) = 4
```

Comment: Took me a while since this was part of a massive query so testing took a little while. Thanks Juergen, it works really well.